# XML to XML using XSLT through C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I've got an XML file (book) that I need to make changes to before creating an output XML file.

I've got an XSLT Transform file which does part of the job fine, but I'm needing to go one step further which is where I'm struggling.

In C# I'm using an XslCompiledTransform object to trigger the transform task and this not works because the XML file output is empty ...

code behind

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(Server.MapPath("~/RSS91.xslt"));
transform.Transform(Server.MapPath("~/book.xml"), Server.MapPath("~/output.xml"));
```

RSS91.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="title"/>
  <xsl:template match="rss">
    <xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
      <br>
        <strong>
          <a href="{link}" target="_main">
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
          </a>
        </strong>
        <br></br>
        <xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </br>
      <br></br>
      <xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/>
      <br></br>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="description">
    <br>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </br>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

book.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss>
  <title></title>
</rss>
```

Comment: The transformation is matching <rss>, then selecting each channel/item tag. There are none, and so clearly no XML is created in the output.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by @HenkHoltermann, an empty output XML document is to be expected, given the input XML and the XSLT stylesheet you apply.

Your XSLT stylesheets works fine - it is just that you transform an input XML that has nothing to do with it. Let me explain why.

In your stylesheet, there are two templates that match for

- `rss` elements
- `description` elements

When you transform this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss>
  <title></title>
</rss>
```

the first template is triggered, because there is an `rss` element in the input. But the first instruction inside this template is

```
<xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
```

which does nothing since there is neither a `channel` nor an `item` element inside it in your input XML. Thus, the first template is triggered, but does not output anything as a whole.

The second template is not triggered at all, there is no `description` element in your input XML.

To summarize, usually, an XSLT stylesheet is tailored to a certain type of input XML documents. It relies either on a certain *structure* being present in the input XML or on certain *values* or other content being present. An exception this is an identity transform which can be applied to any kind of well-formed XML.

---

> I'm sorry but I have not figured out what I need to do

Well, I have two pieces of advice.

- This accurately describes what you are doing:

> Imagine that you own a cow. If you completely oversimplify the process, cows transform grass into milk. That's simple - you input grass and cows output milk. The reason why this works is that the cow's digestive system "knows" how to turn grass into milk. But it is only prepared to masticate grass. Now, you are feeding your cow stones and old tires. Why do you expect it to happily produce milk?
>
> Learn about XSLT yourself. Read a book, study examples, work through a tutorial.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have not figured out what I need to do